# VB6 to Java Converter

Tags: java, vb6, converters

I have some code needs to be converted to Java from VB6. I found many tools in google for VB.NET. Any free tools which can do my job?

Comment: I'd consider rewriting it from scratch. Another option is VB6 > VB.NET > Java...

Comment: yea...That would be nice...but i just want a time saving option.. :)

Comment: @CodeJack - 'home' is talking about saving time ... **in the long term**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea might be to look at [Jabaco](http://www.jabaco.org/product.html).

This product is an IDE, compiler, and library that lets you work in a **very** VB6-like language that compiles to Java bytecode.  So you might begin this way and gradually convert parts of the application to Java by hand over time.

This is similar to one of the more successful ways to migrate a VB6 codebase to .Net, but without the Interop issues.

Jabaco *is not* VB6, so conversion isn't trivial.  But it is much closer than VB.Net ever was, so this makes it a little less painful.  Ideally you'd have a strong VB6 developer who knows some Java and a strong Java developer who knows some VB6 work together to make it all happen.

Like any new development system, it will take some investment in time to get up to speed with its quirks, differences from VB6, and various construct substitutions required to get a working program.

Since it is free at present it costs nothing to take a look!